# KeePass - Backup to Telegram?

Tags: keepass

I am looking for ways to backup my KeePass file to prevent loss. Of course, I saved it to my computer and my phone. But what if I lose access to my computer and my phone at once? Where should I back it up? Telegram seems to be the best solution! I can send the file to myself and only thing I need to access my Telegram account is my SIM card - which - if I lose it - can be replaced by my operator. What do you think about it?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a security question. Despite the fact that you want to have a backup of a password database, the same could be said of any file. So, your question amounts to "can I use Telegram as a backup scheme", and the answer is still pretty broad.

Comment: How about you just push it to Dropbox or your favorite cloud storage service? The file's security is in the strength of your password, not the actual bits on the disk.

Comment: Yeah, but I store Dropbox password in my KeePass...

Comment: @schroeder, in fact this question isn't the same as "can I use Telegram as a backup scheme" to which the answer would be "it depends.". In this case the answer clearly is "yes (assuming Telegram actually does this sort of service for you)" because of the way password databases tend to be structured and protected.

Comment: I personally back it up on an usb thumb drive. That should be enough

Answer (score 1):

For the course of this answer I am going to assume that Telegram actually does store your files for you (in cleartext) and actually allows you the recovery using a new valid SIM card for an indefinite period of time. When in doubt contact the Telegram support and ask for clarification.

---

**Yes, this works and would be secure.**

KeePass databases are encrypted and authenticated files which can only be unlocked given the correct set of credentials (e.g. keyfile, password, ...), thereby storing it at an untrusted location is perfectly fine.

However, I'd recommend a more involved backup solution. The first step would be to backup a specifically crafted KeePass file on Telegram, which only contains your credentials for standard backup targets (e.g. dropbox, google drive, AWS S3, ...) and can be secrured using your normal master password.  The next step is to setup automatic backups in your normal KeePass database to those locations. This has the advantage that you can recover your password database in case you lost all your physical backups but also provides an easy-to-use solution which doesn't force you to do a database backup by hand upon each change.

Comment: Why not just put KeePass DB on Dropbox? You only need 2 passwords, Dropbox and KeePass.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and suggesting that interesting think with SYNCing. Could you, or anyone else, please, suggest any other way like this - backup for scenario that I do not have to remember any other pass and I lose access to my PC and phone? But I do not want to have my database totally public...

Comment: Neil, yeah, just 2, but I decided to make my database password super-secure (60 character, including <AZ><az><09><symbols>) and I did all that to keep ALL my passwords here :/ Therefore - I really do not want to bother remembering other password, I can not afford to lose that database and I do not want to make it completely public, too.

Comment: @NeilSmithline the OP wanted to put the database on Telegram, so I proposed a construction which allows for full security and easy maintainability at the same time without a need for an extra password to get the database (file) back.

Comment: @user109926, I may have formulated this badly, but I implicitely assumed that the crafted database uses the same password as your master database. This way you can get the storage-locations-database back via Telegram, decrypt using your main password and then go to your cloud service provider of choice and get your current database version back from there.